Зміщення наголосу у словосполученні "справа смаку"
Чи існує таке явище в українській мові коли наголос зміщується в словосполученнях? От, наприклад в слові "смаку" наголос падає на "у", але словосполучення "справа смаку" звучить природніше з наголосом на "а".

Моя думка (нічим об'єктивно не обґрунтована): (1) явище загалом існує (на жаль, не можу знайти прикладів); (2) конкретно до цього випадку воно стосунку не має, тут це радше підсвідомий вплив російської (я не стверджую, що це обов'язково калька; і навіть якщо це калька, то калькування — це зовсім не завжди щось погане; але в будь-якому разі якась частина мовців, вимовляючи, може тримати в голові рос. де́ло вку́са) чи польської (де наголос майже завжди на передостанній склад) у частини мовців.

@Sasha < явище загалом існує (на жаль, не можу знайти прикладів); > Dobra častına zajmennıkôv: tebé, ale do tébe.
